# Django : render not passing context variable to template

Tags: python, django

I have this views function to fetch userid and accountnumber from AWS Dynamodb :

```
 def dsctbl2(request):
  dynamodb=boto3.client('dynamodb', region_name='us-west-2')
  response = dynamodb.scan(
    TableName='User-Account')
  filtered = response['Items']
  length = len(filtered)
  for k in range(length):
    accnum = filtered[k]['AccountNum']['S']
    uid = filtered[k]['UserId']['S']
    f = dict(AccountNum=accnum,userID=uid)
    rows = list(f.items())
  return render('useradd.html',{'rows': rows})
```

I have tried almost everything but the rows value is just not getting passed to my template. I even tried passing a simple string value and even that is not getting passed. This is my template table where I wish to display the userid and accountnum.

```
 <div class="mytable">
   <table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>Account #</th>
    <th>User Id</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
   <tbody>
      {% for row in rows %}
   <tr>
    <td>{{ row.AccountNum }}</td>
    <td>{{ row.UserId }}</td>
   </tr>
        {% endfor %}
   </table>
 </div>
```

When I hit the template , nothing shows up. No values are getting displayed except the table headings. Why is render not passing the context variable (list value)from my views to template ? I have been stuck with for about 6 hours ! Can someone resolve this issue ?

Comment: This code would not work at all, because `render` is expecting three arguments as Exprator says and would therefore interpret `{'rows': rows}` as the template name and throw a TemplateDoesNotExist error. Therefore, it seems that your view is not actually getting called. You probably need to show the urls.py and explain what URL you are going to.

Comment: I added request as an argument but still nothing is displayed on the template page.

Comment: I am not getting any error though

Comment: Yes, because as I said **your view is not getting called**. As I also said, you should post your urls.py and explain which URL you are actually visiting.

Comment: Okay.. But it's kind of a mess .. the urls.py

Comment: You are right in saying that the views is not getting called at all

Answer (score 2):

```
return render(request,'useradd.html',{'rows': rows})
```

you need to pass request as first parameter,

Comment: I tried that.. doesn't work. Nothing shows up on the template page except the table headings

Comment: url(r'^adm/dsctbl2/', admviews.dsctbl2, name='dsctbl2'),

Comment: adm is the app name

Comment: you should add the full urls.py in the question,